# how to execute .next() in for loop for i times

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I want to execute `.next()` in a for loop for `i` times. something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
   $(".tag").next(i).hide();
}
```

I saw the `.next()` documentation. It says that `.next()` does not accepts any parameters like `i` or a number like 5. It just accepts the selectors as parameter.
Please help me to solve my problem. Remember that `.nextAll()` could not help me.

Comment: Do you have to use .next()? Can you just use a nested for loop?

Comment: You will use `i` here for element `index` so the correct code should be `$('.tag').eq(i).next().hide()` then for delay you can use `.delay(i * 1000)` so your code should be something like `$('.tag').eq(i).next().delay(i * 1000).hide()`

Comment: @Zachary McGee No, It may be too long

Comment: @HamidRezaGhafouri what do you mean it may be too long?

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee can you explain more about your way. i think i did not understand you. please write the codes

Comment: I am at work and cannot test but 

Something like:

var tags = container.getElementsByTagName('.tag');

for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].hide();
}